# Not able to create report on protractor tests in docker container

Tags: docker, protractor, docker-compose, jasmine-reporters

If I run my tests on `protractor` on my machine the report is properly generated and screenshots saved. My objective now is to do automated testing where I'm gonna use `docker`.

My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    image: app
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome
    ports:
      - 4444:4444
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
  protractor:
    volumes:
      - ./tmp:/assets/tmp
    image: test
    command: "dockerize -wait http://selenium:4444 -wait http://app:9000 -timeout 60m protractor /assets/conf.js"
```

The problem with this is that the report and screenshots are not being saved to the volume. If instead of using the `docker` image for protractor I use the local one it works correctly with the app and selenium images.

For testing purposes I've added the folder manually on my volume (local) and can see that the folder is being removed, so I'm assuming the linkage is correct.

My `conf.js` as the method  `onPrepare` to add the reporter which look like

```
onPrepare: function() {
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
            baseDirectory: '/assets/tmp/screenshots'
        }));
    }
}
```

The reporter used is [protractor-html-screenshot-reporter](https://github.com/jintoppy/protractor-html-screenshot-reporter).

My question is where could the problem be, path on the report, permissions, etc and what could be a fix or alternative approach

Thanks in advance

Comment: My immediate thought was permissions, though, since the directory is being deleted, looks like there is a sufficient access to it.

Comment: @alecxe In the `tmp` folder I've added 2 empty folders, one being the `screenshots`. That one is being removed, as in the local flow but then not being added as it should. The other folder keeps unchanged which leads me to think paths and permissions are correct. Any thoughts on what could I do differently to get some more insights on the issue?

Comment: @alecxe it was an issue with `jasmine` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging found that `jasmine` versions were different (local and docker image) and wasn't triggering the method to create the screenshots.

The versions were different because of when `protractor` was installed using `npm install -g protractor` (`2.5.1` vs `4.0.13`).

Creating the image using `protractor` version `2.5.1` fixed the issue.